# Table Header Scroll using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am working on handling two tables one with table has table head and another table has table body.Need help in fixed table head and two table content with proper alignment.while fixing the header i could not align the table content subsequently to it. With help of id i fix the table header.can anyone fix this alignment.Thanks in advance.

> ```
>     <table id="table-1" class="table table-hover">
>         <thead>
>           <tr>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>             <th>test</th>
>           </tr>
>         </thead>
>     <body>
>           <div class="content">
>             <table class="table table-striped">
>          <tbody>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr><tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr><tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr class="bordered">
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center">test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center" data-toggle="modal"
>      id="myBtn"> 
>     test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test</td>
>     <td align="center"> 
>      test</td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test </td>
>     <td align="center"> test  </td>
>     <td>     
>          test
>        </td>
>     <td>   
>     test
>           </td>
>         <td> 
>         test
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     </tbody>
>     </table>
>     <table id="header-fixed"></table>
> var tableOffset = $("#table-1").offset().top;
>
> var $header = $("#table-1 > thead").clone();
>
> var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header);
>
>
>
> $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
>
>     var offset = $(this).scrollTop();
>
>
>
>     if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
>
>         $fixedHeader.show();
>
>     }
>
>     else if (offset < tableOffset) {
>
>         $fixedHeader.hide();
>
>     }
>
> });
> ```

[Here is the Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1jkz4po3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to show a *fixed* `thead` (clone table) on top of a scrolling table (original table).

Check this **working demo**: [CODEPEN demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPwgma)

Is this what you are looking for? How it works:

`HTML` part:

```
<!-- a CONTAINER for everything -->
<div id="table-holder">
  <!-- a fixed TOP that is visible or hidden on scroll -->
  <div id="table-top">
    <!-- a TABLE CLONE that contains the THEAD -->
    <table id="table-clone" border="1"></table>
  </div>
  <!-- a CONTAINER that allows the original table to scroll -->
  <div id="table-scroll">
    <!-- the ORIGINAL TABLE -->
    <table id="table-original" border="1">
      <!-- the THEAD -->
      <thead>....</thead>
      <!-- the TBODY -->
      <tbody>....</tbody>
    </table>
  </div><!-- endof: #table-scroll -->
</div><!-- endof: #table-holder -->
```

`CSS` part:

```
#table-holder {
  position:relative;
}
#table-top {
  width:100%;  /* important */
  position:absolute;  /* important -> always at top */
  display:none;  /* hidden at first */
}
#table-scroll {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y:scroll; /* important */
}
table {
  width:100%;
}
```

`JS` part (jQuery):

```
// set main table html vars
var $table_top = $("#table-top");
var $table_scroll = $("#table-scroll");
var $table_clone = $("#table-clone");
var $thead_original = $("#table-original thead");
var $thead_clone = $thead_original.clone();
// copy the original THEAD into table-top
$table_clone.append($thead_clone);
// adjust table-top width (consider the width of the Y scrollbar)
$table_top.css("width", $thead_original.width())
// set vars needed to show/hide table-top
var thead_height = $thead_original.height();
//// set the threshold for the show/hide action
var visible_top = $table_scroll.offset().top;
var table_top_visible = 0;
// set onScroll action: show/hide table-top
$table_scroll.on("scroll",function(){
  // the the current offset of the original THEAD
  var thead_top = $thead_original.offset().top;
  //// get the position of the bottom of the THEAD
  var thead_bottom = thead_top + thead_height;
  // check if the original THEAD is hidden
  if (thead_bottom < visible_top) {
    // if the original is hidden -> show the clone
    if (!table_top_visible) {
      table_top_visible = 1;
      $table_top.fadeIn();
    }
  } else {
    // else, the original is visible -> hide the clone
    if (table_top_visible) {
      table_top_visible = 0;
      $table_top.fadeOut();
    }
  }
});
```